# Is it possible to auto delete All hadoop logs

Tags: hadoop, logging

I have tried to delete hadoop logs automatically using below `.sh` script using cron. But still logs are not deleting. Is there any way to delete hadoop logs automatically in ubuntu?

```
find /path/to/files/ -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Not sure but there will be be configuration using which you can specify the time or size after will you want to delete or overwrite the logs. [Hotnwoks](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/137029/how-to-rotate-hdfs-daemon-log.html) [coludera](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/)

Comment: Anyone can suggest here the approach to delete hadoop logs

Comment: it got resolved